# Experiment with tf2 in Python without a full ROS install

Tags: ros, transform, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a mac and want to experiment and pay around with tf,  eigen and quaterions in a jupyter notebook without doing a full ros install (because AFAIK the Mac install for ROS is still problematic.) I am not sure how or what subset I would need to install to achieve this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326268/experiment-with-tf2-in-python-without-a-full-ros-install/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every package properly declares it's dependencies. If you pick any package from there you can introspect it's dependencies and build from there.

There are tools like the rosinstall_generator that can help you automatically resolve dependencies and help you get the source for the packages that you need.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1